# Editing the settings that are available through raspi-config without using raspi-config

Tags: raspbian, boot-issues, driver, raspi-config, opengles

I have a Pi 2 and decided to check the new experimental OpenGL driver available in the latest version of Raspbian Jessie. Alas! the thing is really buggy. After enabling it my Pi, (through `raspi-config`) no longer boots and the connected official 7" Pi display shows only the initial colorful square but nothing after that. After reading online it seems that in order for the Pi to boot after enabling the GL driver a display has to be connected to the HDMI. Nice...

So in order to avoid attaching and detaching my desktop display I decide to check if I can disable the GL driver by simply editing X and Y files on the SD card from my notebook.

The problem is that I have no idea which setting (or even settings!) the enabling of the GL driver has triggered so I haven't got a clue which configuration file (or files) I have to edit.

Searching online gave me no fruitful results so I'm asking here hoping that I can resolve this issue.

PS: As mentioned I do have a HDMI screen however knowing which settings the `raspi-config` actually changes would be really helpful not only for the situation described in this post.

Comment: Put your SD card in a another box and look at config.txt.  I'd expect any changes for opengl to be at the end and reasonably obvious.

Comment: The problem is that I couldn't find any `config.txt` inside `/boot`. Really weird...

Comment: Are you using NOOBS?  I think that does odd things with partitions.  If you use plain Raspbian there will only be one partition visible on a Window's machine.  That should contain config,txt, kernel.img, etc.

Comment: No, I use the plain Jessie (full not lite) image. However now that you have mentioned TWO partition I realized I have been looking inside the Linux partition where you have the standard `/boot` folder instead of the **boot partition**. LOL I found my `config.txt`. :P As for Windows - I'm using Linux on my desktop PC and notebook so no problem with invisible partitions. :D

Comment: Did you manage to find the entries in config.txt?

Comment: Yeap. However I did that after disabling the driver using my HDMI monitor. After that I copied the `config.txt` to my `/home` as `config_gl_disabled.txt`, then enabled it again and copied the new `config.txt` to my `/home` as `config_gl_enabled.txt`. After that I did a `diff` on both by calling `diff config_gl_*` in the terminal and got that the `dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d` was set to `on`. I did all this in such a complicated manner since I didn't know the name of the property (or properties) that was changed by toggling the GL driver. If you want you can post this as the answer. :)

Comment: You did all the work.  You can always self answer.

Comment: Thanks for the partitions tip. I'm relatively new to the Pi and I was really surprised when the `/boot` was completely empty even though there were plenty of things that were supposed to be there.

Comment: For future reference `raspi-config` doesn't have any special powers, it is just a shell script that runs other commands for you.  So if you are ever curious about this kind of thing and can understand shell, it's all pretty straightforward: I think the script in is in `/usr/bin`.

Comment: I know that it's a shell script. Thanks for the info where to look. :)

Comment: Actually it's `/usr/bin`, sorry (edited previous comment too).

Comment: Thanks. I added your tip in my answer (if you mind me doing that just remove it :)). I also wrote why it this might not be the most efficient way if you are a beginner and have no idea what to look for. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The setting that changes inside the `config.txt` is `dtoverlay`. Whenever the GL driver is enabled it is set to `dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d` else commented out.

I had difficulties even finding the `config.txt` since I was looking in the wrong partition (thanks for the tip, @joan !)

In order to easily find what setting has changed and since I didn't know the name of the setting (or settings) to begin with I had to use my HDMI monitor for the Pi to be able to boot properly. After that I disabled the driver and copied the `config.txt` inside my `/home` under the name of `config_gl_disabled.txt`. After that I enabled it again and did the same thing but this time the name of the copy was `config_gl_enabled.txt`. Without rebooting (so that I screw things up again) I simply used `diff`:

```
diff config_gl_*
```

and the `dtoverlay` showed as thing that was changed.

In addition as pointed by @goldilocks the `raspi-config` is just a shell script which can be found in `/usr/bin` (you can also see the installation location in the [`raspi-config.install`](https://github.com/asb/raspi-config/blob/master/debian/raspi-config.install)) or in the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/asb/raspi-config/blob/master/raspi-config). The problem is that for example in my case I was unable to find anything indicating `vc4-kms-v3d` or `dtoverlay` so in some situations it might be nearly impossible to follow the breadcrumbs since external scripts are probably also being invoked, which change this and that. So without prior knowledge where to look I believe that `diff`-ing (or similar way) is the easiest way for beginners.